# Spring Cloud Gateway - Streaming of Large Requests

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

**Question**

When sending a large http request (e.g. 100MB) to Spring Cloud Gateway, does it read the complete request into memory before forwarding it to the downstream service?

**Assumption/Guess**

From the memory consumption and timing, it seems to work this way but I cannot find any information about this in the documentation. Can anyone confirm if the assumption is correct or not?

**Are there workarounds/solutions?**

If the assumption is correct: Is it possible to make the Spring Cloud Gateway "stream" the request immediately after the route has been determined (e.g. after reading the headers)? Because reading the complete request into memory can quickly turn into a bottleneck when multiple "big" requests are coming in at the same time. Or are there some other recommended workarounds for this issue?

Comment: It should stream unless you are using a filter or predicate that reads the body

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast response and hint [spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb)!

Actually in our case it was the RetryFilter which was causing the effect that we were observing. After deactivation the streaming is working fine and the memory constraint is even mentioned in the documentation of the RetryFilter.

According to documentation I expected that the filter would only be applied to GET requests on default. But maybe this was a misunderstanding. Removing the filter definitely solved the memory issues for us.